# Does Google Map supporting Apple Watch in iOS Development?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, apple-watch

I want to add Google Map into Apple Watch. I am running one app which has already integrated Google Map. I want to integrate some functionality with the Apple Watch kit.

Is there any way to do that? Please share your thought if you have any.

Comment: If i am not wrong i don't think for now any sdk available from google ; may be in future they provide support

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya, Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Google Maps SDK for watchOS at the moment, but you can use the Google Maps REST API from watchOS.